# Extracting specific strings from a file using bash script

Tags: regex, string, bash, awk

I want to extract certain strings and their values from a log file having text as below using bash code;

```
key=DATA&channel=WEB&number=234xxxxxxxxxx
state=MOB&dest=3000&key=SMS&number=234xxxxxxxxxxx
```

The desired result should be;

```
key=DATA number=234xxxxxxxxxx
key=SMS  number=234xxxxxxxxxx
```

Thanks.

Comment: @mjuares, I have tried the following;

`awk -F "&" '{OFS = "\n"; print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' | grep -E 'key|number'  <filename>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use grep.

```
grep -o '\b\(key\|number\)=[^&]*' file | paste - -
```

**OR**

```
awk -F'&' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/^key|number/) print $i}' file | paste - -
```

Comment: thanks but there was a mistake in my initial desired output. I want to capture the actual key value.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Marking your answer and the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with `read` and `printf` from the command line using **parameter expansion/substring extraction**:

```
$ ( while read -r line; do printf "%-10s  %s\n" "${line%%&*}" "${line##*&}"; done < dat/keyval.log )
key=DATA    number=234xxxxxxxxxx
state=MOB   number=234xxxxxxxxxxx
```

**note:** run in a subshell above, but you can run it without the subshell as well.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
awk -F\& '{print $1,$NF}' file
key=DATA number=234xxxxxxxxxx
state=MOB number=234xxxxxxxxxxx
```

Separate data with `&`, then just print first and last field.